# htaccess subdomain folder in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain

I need some help on the htaccess subdomain to be pointed to specific file in a folder for a wordpress site.

Currently I have this in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.domain\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdomain/
RewriteRule (.*) /subdomain/$1

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^subdomain/(.*)$ http://subdomain.domain.com/$1
```

When the user enters subdomain.domain.com it will access the domain.com/subdomain folder and when it enter domain.com/subdomain it will redirect to subdomain.domain.com. (this is exactly what i want to happen)

Problem is inside the wordpress of the subdomain because it still referrer to the main domain (i.e. the images is still domain.com/wp-content/uploads/... instead of subdomain.domain.com/wp-content/uploads/... or at least domain.com/subdomain/wp-content/uploads/...).

How do I make the subdomain access the its folder in .htaccess?

Been doing this for days now. please help. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your WordPress installation's general settings.

[image: WordPress General Settings]

Change your `Site Address (URL)` to `http://subdomain.domain.com/`. This will fix the links generated on all the blog pages to use the sub-domain instead of the main one.

Comment: thanks. this solved the problem. now I only need help with permalinks and the permalink page itself. the page is displaying these errors

Warning: is_writable() [function.is-writable]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/) is not within the allowed path(s):...

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /clientdata/apache-www/b...

and i can't solve the 404 error problem after changing permalinks even if I change the .htaccess of my subdomain.

anyway, thanks and more thanks if you can also help me on this one.

Comment: the error displays this path
 /clientdata/apache-www/b/o/domain.com/www/subdomain/wp-admin/includes/misc.php

how can i remove the www on that path?

Comment: Please take a look at http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks especially the section titled `Using "Pretty" permalinks`. It outlines all the requirements for permalink to work, such as, adding `Options +FollowSymLinks` to your subdomain htaccess file.